# I am getting an error app.get is not a function, But other people can run this code without any error, I want to know why this is happening?

Tags: javascript

I am getting a problem that app.get is not a function, what have I done wrong?

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express;enter code here
const port = 80;
app.get('practice/javascript/tut21nodejs/home.html',(req, res)=>{
    res.send("This is my first express app");
});
app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log(`The application has started successfully at port ${port}`)
})
```

Comment: Do you have the module express installed in your server?

Comment: ```const app = express;enter your code here``` should be ```const app = express;```. I don't think you need the ```.html``` in the url either.

Comment: You need to call express as a function in order to get an express instance. https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all, line 2 should be `const app = express()`. Second of all, for me, port 80 doesn't work (for me), try using port 8080, and finally, try changing "practice/javascript/tut21nodejs/home.html" to "/practice/javascript/tut21nodejs/home.html". Hope this fixes it for you.

Comment: Review: Would be nice if you explained the reasoning for your changes. Otherwise looks OK.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now the code is running successfully. Thanks